# Random Grid Layout using PHP with content from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I have a grid layout designed. It's a full width fluid layout with no gaps in between. I need to randomise the content on each page load. I have blocks of different sizes. They add up to 7. Some blocks take up two spaces of the row, others one.

I need a way to randomly output content from a database in each block of the grid. Currently I have set up php functions that randomise the blocks and content but I only have a preset number of blocks and content that are the same.

What would be the best way to do this? I currently have repeating content.

Comment: can you give some sample code/db queries that you are already using? This would be helpful.

Comment: Please provide us with some of your current implementation code.  This way we can taylor our response to what you already have rather than coding an entirely new system.

Comment: just use `int myVariableName = rand(0,7)` to generate a random number between 0 and 7. Or, if you have a more specific question, ask it with some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for ORDER BY rand() SQL query.

[This question will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788271/mysql-select-by-random) if so.